# Hover animation contained within parent

Tags: css, hover

I have a JSFiddle here with a nice hover effect I'm working on but I would like to know if it's possible to have the hover effect contained within the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/cyXKx/

Everything works well except the far right list items and bottom row when hovered go outside the grid. Ideally I'd like them to grow from the top right point on the right hand side and from the bottom left on the bottom row.

I hope this makes sense, I just want to know if it's possible?

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class="tearsheets">
  <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span><img class="galleryImg" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/transport"></span></a></li>

     </ul>
```

and the CSS

```
ul.tearsheets{
        overflow:hidden;
        clear:both;
        max-width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    .tearsheets li span {
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:middle;
       height:110px;

    }
    .tearsheets{
        padding:18px 18px 108px 18px;
    }
    .tearsheets li{
        float:left;
        line-height:110px;
        width:160px;
        list-style:none;
        height:110px;
        background-color:#9C9B9B;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 1px 1px 0;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
    .tearsheets li a{
        display:block;

    }
    .tearsheets li span img{
        padding-top:10px;
        z-index: 0;
        max-height:90px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
    .tearsheets li a:hover{
        height:221px;
        background-color:#9C9B9B;
        width:321px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1000000;
    }
    .tearsheets li a:hover span{
        padding-top:10px;

    }
    .tearsheets li a:hover span img{
        max-height:180px;
    }
```

If anyone can help me with this that would be amazing, if it works on IE8-9 even better - I'm not too worried about IE8 animation at this stage.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as duality_, but executed a little differently: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/tTqqa/)

New CSS:

```
.tearsheets li.right a:hover {
    right: 0;
}
.tearsheets li.bottom a:hover {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

JS (using jQuery):

```
function adjust() {
  $('ul.tearsheets').each(function () {
    var items = $(this).children(),
        num_items = items.length,
        num_per_row, i, n;

    if (num_items) {
      items.removeClass('right bottom');

      // find number of items per row
      n = 0;
      items.each(function (i) {
        var l = $(this).position().left;
        if (l <= n) {
          num_per_row = i;
          return false;
        } else {
          n = l;
        }
      });

      // apply 'right' class to the last column of items
      if (num_per_row > 1) {
        for (i = num_per_row - 1; i < num_items; i += num_per_row) {
          items.eq(i).addClass('right');
        }
      }

      // apply 'bottom' class to last row of items
      n = items.eq(-1).position().top;
      if (items.eq(0).position().top < n) {
        $(items.get().reverse()).each(function () {
          var item = $(this), t = item.position().top;
          if (t == n) {
            item.addClass('bottom');
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

$(window).on('resize', adjust);
adjust();
```

Comment: This looks good but again the image is trying to left first :s Maybe it can't be done - thanks for the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "the image is trying to left first"?

Comment: When you hover - there is a split second where the image moves right (sorry not good with those) then moves quickly left to where it should be, is there anyway to make it go left first and not judder right? Sorry it could be my browser too :s

Answer (score 2):

Dont waste the Javascript. This is a little more direct.

```
    .tearsheets li:nth-of-type(even) >  a:hover {
    left:-160px;
    }
```

Just add that to your css and youre done.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know

Answer (score 1):

**Sure thing. Here's the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/cyXKx/3/).**

What I did.

**First:** HTML stays the same.

**Second:** for CSS I invent two classes for your `<li>`s: `last-x` and `last-y`. The first means, that it doesn't have any items to the right (even at the end of the list). The second is the same, but looking vertically.

CSS code:

```
.tearsheets li.last-x a:hover{ left: -161px; }
.tearsheets li.last-y a:hover{ top: -111px; }
```

**Third:** Add jQuery and sprinkle some jQuery *magic* on it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var $tearsheets = $(".tearsheets");
    var line_length = Math.floor($tearsheets.width() / $tearsheets.find("li:first").width());
    var items_count = $tearsheets.find("li").length;
    var full_lines_count = Math.floor(items_count / line_length);
    var index = 0; // somehow the internal index inside .each() doesn't work :-/
    $tearsheets.find("li").each(function(i) {
        var item_position = i + 1;
        var items_on_the_right = line_length - (i % line_length) - 1;
        //console.log(items_on_the_right + ", " + items_count + ", " + item_position);
        if (items_on_the_right > (items_count - item_position))
            items_on_the_right = items_count - item_position;
        if (items_on_the_right == 0)
            $(this).addClass("last-x");

        var current_line = Math.ceil(item_position / line_length);
        $(this).attr("data-current-line", current_line);
        if (current_line >= full_lines_count)
            $(this).addClass("last-y");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works unless you resize the window after the function has been run. You'll probably need to call it again when the window resizes.

Comment: Developers resize windows. How many times have you seen a user resize a window? :)

Comment: Hi thanks for this it looks really good - only problem I have is that the first row last col one doesn't do it and third row last col and the first col last row. Is there any way to make these to the animation from the correct corners? Good to know it can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for this is using CSS3. You can do it just adding the following:

```
ul.tearsheets > li:nth-child(even):hover {
    position:relative;
    right:161px;
}
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyXKx/5/).

With that the `li` will move from right to left, but I don't really know if that's what you wanted. You can change that behaviour by adding the following properties:

```
transition:none;
-webkit-transition: none;
-moz-transition:none;  
-o-transition:none;
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyXKx/6/).

Note that, as I have used a CSS3 selector, this solution won't work in old browsers, such as IE8.

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately the transition isn't smooth, I'm getting a judder where the image goes left then right :s